# Get latest dates from an array per object group in Powershell

Tags: arrays, datetime, powershell, greatest-n-per-group

I have an array *$data* :

```
PS> $data
Datum                  User                   Computer                                      
-----                  ---------              --------                                      
10/06/2013 13:10:56    geb1@TESTDOMAIN.COM    DC1$                                          
10/06/2013 13:09:25    geb2@TESTDOMAIN.COM    DC2$                                          
10/06/2013 10:05:13    geb2@TESTDOMAIN.COM    DC2$                                          
7/06/2013 16:32:47     geb1@TESTDOMAIN.COM    DC1$
```

I want to get the latest dates from the $data array for each computer like this:

```
PS> $result
Datum                  User                   Computer                                      
-----                  ---------              --------                                      
10/06/2013 13:10:56    geb1@TESTDOMAIN.COM    DC1$                                          
10/06/2013 13:09:25    geb2@TESTDOMAIN.COM    DC2$
```

I really couldn't get this result. Could you please help me on this?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

```
$data | Foreach-Object {$_.Datum = [DateTime]$_.Datum; $_} | 
Group-Object Computer | 
Foreach-Object {$_.Group | Sort-Object Datum | Select-Object -Last 1}
```

Comment: This solved my problem. I got the exact result on my screen. Thank you!!

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you use the $GET_[]; statement?

Comment: I also think its way easier that you put youre data in a databse because if you kept on putting it in a array the site will be much slower

Comment: I think you're talking about php but it's powershell. thanks anyway.

Answer (score 1):

This should work, but I can't test it now:

```
$result =$data | sort computer,{ [datetime]$_.datum } -desc | group computer | % { $_.group[0] }
```

Comment: It gave me the last two rows as result. The way you go is good but it doesn't work. Thanks anyway!